# Giving gifts while unemployed

Tags: quran, hadith, source-identification

Since Pandemic I had not found work and now I am visiting my home country with my children first time. There is a tradition of giving chocolates, gifts and clothes.

Buying all things for everyone put me on a very very tight budget which impact my family situation.

Islam says to gift your relative and when you visit someone gift them as well and at one place it is mention that Allah give someone who gives even more.

With all this, what is one suppose to do according to Islam? On one side if one doesn’t give family gift they might be seen as stingy and if one gives out then it doesn’t save anything for my family.

What Islam says about someone in my condition?

P.S - My mom had been supporting my family financially during this time.

Comment: Giving gifts is recommended, not obligatory. If you don't want to do it, then don't. There is no to seek excuses.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your situation is a trial for you.

If you are struggling financially, logically you should not be giving gifts to your relatives and friends. You should conserve your resources while you look out for better opportunities.

There are two reasons why you want to give gifts.

1. **Giving and receiving gifts is encouraged in Islam.** No doubt about it. However it is not meant for someone in your financial situation. Right now you yourself are dependent on others.
2. **You fear that people will think you are stingy.** Don't worry too much about what people think about you.

Pray to God to ease your financial problems (and akhirah also). May Allah give you the strength to overcome your trials.

**Note to Readers:** If you are down-voting my answer, you are most welcome. Please provide reasoning in the comments. I promise, I will not argue with you. I am writing this since unexplained down-votes have perplexed me earlier in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. With regards to gifts as UmH stated it is not obligatory. It is a beautiful practice to implement as seen below:

Abu Hurayra reported that the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, "Give gifts and you will love one another."
Al-Adab Al-Mufrad 594
Grade:   Hasan (Al-Albani)

However, giving gifts in a physical form is not the only way to give someone a gift. Reciting something on their behalf and making intention for the rewards to their account can be considered a gift to them. By definition a gift means "a thing given willingly to someone without payment; a present."

**Recommendation**

If you cannot give a gift then to smile at your mom for example is charity. Helping her out physically with chores. Perhaps teaching her Quran and hadith. Or taking a walk with her in the park. Perhaps massaging her feet or both of you guys have fun at the bowling alley. There are various ways to be kind and loving without giving a gift.

**Have a nice day!**